# postgres 9.1: role public does not exist

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.1

I understand `public` is not a typical role in postgres:

`dav-gis=# \duS public
           List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of 
-----------+------------+-----------`

But why can I revoke all privileges on a schema from `public`, but not assign another role to `public`? E.g.,

```
db=# REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA "eia" FROM "public";
REVOKE
db=# GRANT "eia-ro" TO "public";
ERROR:  role "public" does not exist
```

I'd like to only give public users read access through the read-only role, but perhaps this is just out of sync with how public access works in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Evan Carroll said, there is no "public" role. The manual has [this to say:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

> The key word PUBLIC indicates that the privileges are to be granted
>       to all roles, including those that might be created later. PUBLIC
>       can be thought of as an implicitly defined group that always
>       includes all roles. Any particular role will have the sum of
>       privileges granted directly to it, privileges granted to any role
>       it is presently a member of, and privileges granted to PUBLIC.

...

> Unlike the case with privileges, membership in a role cannot be
>       granted to PUBLIC.

Comment: that helps "implicitly defined group that always includes all roles"

Answer (score 0):

There is no role, "public". There is a [schema `public`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html). The default role of the superuser is `postgres`. You don't want to revoke privileges to it or mess with it. Keep it locked in PostgreSQL. Keep it as `trust` with the operating system. Then in order to use it, you have to have it configured with `sudo` or have root access to the box (in which case, if compromised, you have far more dire problems).